# Executing CGI through Ruby web app behind Passenger

Tags: ruby, cgi, fossil

I have a Rack app (call it Rails, Sinatra, etc.) running through Passenger with nginx as front server. I'm currently running on another place fossil-scm via CGI with multiple repos.

I want to fuse those two making a request to the Ruby app so that the app can do the CGI request to fossil, and obtain the result back, add/modify/analyze whatever, and send it to the client.

Normal fossil operations that can be done through the command line I have no problem. But to display the content of the tickets/wiki/etc. I need to run it through CGI but I don't want having CGI files for each repo lying around.

I think it can/should be done with Ruby CGI lib by passing the ENV from rack to it and obtaining the response, but I'm not really sure how to.

Comment: So i guess either no one knows, or I wasn't explicit enough. I just need to call a cgi command from ruby :(